# Errors in binary comparison in C

Tags: c, perl, sockets

I hava a Perl program, which connects a socket, receive binaries on socket, read this binaries, and compare with others binaries for me to know if there are my binaries received on socket. Look:

**perlProgram.pl**

```
# some code here ...

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => $host, PeerPort => 666, Proto => 'tcp');   

$sock->sockopt(SO_LINGER, pack("ii", 1, 0));


# some code here for another porposes...
# ...


read($sock, $buff, 0xfffff);

close($sock);

if (($v = index $buff, "\xC7\x44\x24\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\xC7\x04\x24\x00\x00\x00\x00\x89\x44\x24\x04") >= 0) {
    $offset = $v;

    printf "your offset is %08x\n", $offset;
} else {
    if (($v = index $buff, "\x89\x44\x24\x10\xA1\xBC\xA5\x0F\x08\x89\x44\x24\x04\xe8") >= 0) {
        $offset = $v;

    printf "your offset is %08x\n", $offset;
    } else {
        print "Could not find your binaries\n";
        exit;
    }
}


# more code here ...
```

This Perl program runs properly, and I'm sure my binaries are coming on socket.
So, I wrote the same code in C, and there are the problem: in C I can't verify if there are my binaries on socket, but I'm sure that the binaries are coming on socket. Look:

**sameProgramInC.c:**

```
// some code here ...

char binaries_1[]="\xc7\x44\x24\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\xc7\x04\x24\x00\x00\x00\x00\x89\x44\x24\x04";
char binaries_2[]="\x89\x44\x24\x10\xa1\xbc\xa5\x0f\x08\x89\x44\x24\x04\xe8";

int indexOf(const unsigned char *data_buffer, const unsigned int length, const unsigned char *needle, const unsigned int needlelen) {
   unsigned int i, j, index=0;
   for(i=0; i < length-needlelen; i++) {
      if(data_buffer[i] == needle[0]){
         index=i;
         for(j=1; j < needlelen; j++){
            if(data_buffer[i+j] != needle[j]){
               index=0;
               break;
            }
         }
         if(index == i){
            return index;
         }
      }
   }
   return index;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int sockfd, buflen;
   struct hostent *host_info;
   struct sockaddr_in target_addr;
   unsigned char read_buffer[0xfffff];

   if((host_info = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL)
      fatal("looking up hostname");

   if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
      fatal("in socket");

   target_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   target_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);   
   target_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host_info->h_addr);
   memset(&(target_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8); // zero the rest of the struct

   if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&target_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
      fatal("connecting to target server");

   // some code here for another porposes...
   // ...

   printf("\n\t Attempting to read memory of the server...");
   bzero(read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer));
   read(sockfd, read_buffer, 0xfffff);

   index = indexOf(read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer), binaries_1, sizeof(binaries_1));    
   if(index != 0){
      printf("\n\t [+] your offset is 0x%08x", index);
   } else {
      index = indexOf(read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer), binaries_2, sizeof(binaries_2));      
      if(index != 0){
         printf("\n\t [+] your offset is 0x%08x", index);
      } else {
         printf("\n\t [-] Fail! Could not find your offset!");
      }
   }

   // more code here
```

So, this C code don't works like my Perl code. Don't have any errors on runtime, just C code can't verify if exists my binaries like Perl code. Then, I try to use `memmem`, and `memcmp` and `strstr`, but also don't works. Why doesn't it work? What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `sizeof(binaries_1)` as search substring length, it includes the trailing zero, change it to `sizeof(binaries_1) - 1`.

Comment: Thank you man! It solved my problem. Off-by-one error, I haven't seen it! Thanks